# Not all JSON properties are sent to server

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just finished building a Xamarin.Forms app and I have published it to Play Store, everything was running fine on local but when I published it on Store, everything messed up. There's the ProGuard issue, Method not found issue - I have resolved these two but this next problem I can't seem to find an answer.

When I was able to load my app installed via Google Play, I tried signing up on my app and I was not able to. So I checked my backend code and there were undefined indexes on my server code - I'm using a PHP backend for this one. Some parameters were carried out, but not all of them.

Here's the model code:

```
[JsonObject("customer")]
public class Customer
{


    [JsonProperty("customer_id")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("middle_name")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("birth_date")]
    public string BirthDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email_address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("contact_number")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
```

Then here's the SQL error in the backend:

```
Query error: Column 'password' cannot be null - Invalid query: INSERT INTO `customer` (`first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `birth_date`, `email_address`, `password`, `contact_number`, `gender`) VALUES ('sunny', '', 'day', '2008-11-05', 'your@gmail.com', NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

So far I have set up the ProGuardconfiguration and set the Linker to SDK and User Assemblies and also tried SDK only - but still no luck. Does it have to do the linker or the ProGuard thing?

Comment: Try getting the json posted from the device. Missing *some* params is usually not a ProGaurd issue

Comment: Try to check if you have post your password from you app to your sever.

Comment: Man that looks like your are really sending a null password. Start from here and post the code that is processing/sending the data to server. Had much fun too when on debug my app was okay but android release was creating a new model with null fields and sending it..